# Multiple root pages in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I currently use wagtail as a blog which is accessible via `example.com/blog` and the admin via `example.com/blog/admin`.

I would like to also use wagtail to create a support (knowledge base) section. This would then be accessible via `example.com/support`.

Would something like the following be possible?

- `example.com/wagtail` - wagtail admin (for both the blog and knowledge base)
- `example.com/blog` - blog section of the site
- `example.com/support` - knowledge base / support section of the site

If the above is not possible I would also be open to having two completely separate wagtail apps in my django project, eg:

- `example.com/blog` - this is a blog wagtail section with its own admin
- `example.com/blog/admin`
- `example.com/support` - this is a separate support wagtail section with its own admin
- `example.com/support/admin`

I'm not entirely sure which option is possible or how to go about getting either one to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your Wagtail CMS can handle multiple sites / page trees. Just create multiple root pages and point your desired domain (+ directory) to them via the **sites** menu in the **settings**. Here is [a more detailed walkthrough](https://wagtail.io/blog/multi-site-wagtail/). I reckon that you used this before to get Wagtail working for the blog/ subdirectory. Just create multiple sites and root pages in the same way.

To create a new root page try to go to the level above your current root page by clicking the little globe icon in the upper left corner of the explorer page or the "pages" button in the explorer menu, also in the upper left corner.